# Returning separate txt files from loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to return the results of each iteration in a loop to be written in a separate text file, but for some reason it does not seem to work. My code is:

```
 for (i in length(traject)){        
      player <-subset(traject[[i]],subset=(dt==1),)
      test<-player  
      write.table(test, file=paste(i, "test.txt", sep=" "))
      head(test)
       }
```

Which only return the last iteration, what do i do wrong to produce the results of all iterations in separate text files?

Extra info: The loop is for each separate player (with different ID's) to gain data via as.ltraj() from the adehabitatLT package.

*(i know there are similar questions on this forum but none could help me in solving this problem)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should add `1:length(traject)` in your `for` loop as in:

```
for (i in 1:length(traject)){   do something }
```

Your loop is only returning one iteretion (the last one) because your index is just `length(traject)` instead you should use `1:length(traject)` for the index `i` to move from the first element all the way to the last one, you can also replace `1:length(traject)` by `seq_len(length(traject))`

Comment: Simple and helpful! Thank you very much!

Comment: Another question concerning this loop; how would i be able to also return a dataframe from each iteration of this loop?

Comment: You can use `assign` function (not so recommended) but it is a easy way to do it. You may want to see `?assign` for further details.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jilber pointed out, you are only iterating over a single number.

Just for reference: If you want to iterate over all items in a vector or list, you can simply do

```
 for (i in traject) {
  #....
 }
```